# How to change $ Cx^2 + Dy^2 + Ex + Fy + G = 0$ to$ (x-h)^2/a^2 ± (y-k)^2/b^2=1 $ using only the variables C, D, E, F, and G

Tags: conic-sections

Or, state the terms a,b,h,and k in terms of C, D, E, F, and/or G

$Cx^2 + Dy^2 + Ex + Fy + G = 0$

$(x-h)^2/a^2 ± (y-k)^2/b^2=1$

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\\ Cx^2+Dy^2+Ex+Fy+G&=&0
\\ C(x^2+ \frac EC x)+D(y^2+\frac FD y)&=&-G
\\ C(x+\frac E{2C})^2-\frac{E^2}{4C}+D(y+\frac F{2D})^2-\frac{F^2}{4D}&=&-G
\\ C(x+\frac E{2C})^2+D(y+\frac F{2D})^2&=&-G+\frac{E^2}{4C}+\frac{F^2}{4D}
\end{array}$$
So
$$\begin{array}{cr}
\\ h=-\frac E{2C}
\\a^2= \frac{-G+\frac{E^2}{4C}+\frac{F^2}{4D}}{C}
\\ k=-\frac F{2D}
\\b^2= \frac{-G+\frac{E^2}{4C}+\frac{F^2}{4D}}{D}
\end{array}$$